# dump data from spark-sql cli query to csv file

Tags: apache-spark-sql

How to write query result to a csv file while using spark-sql cli. below is the spark-sql code that i am using.

```
spark-sql --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=${log4j_setting}"  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=${log4j_setting}" --files log4j.properties -e "SELECT * from table;"
```

Comment: you can redirect the output to file. 
```spark-sql -S  -e "SELECT * from table;"  > filename```